# Symfony 5.1.2 page not found with new project

Tags: php, symfony, controller, routes

I created a new project using Symfony 5.1.2, then I tried to run the server using
`symfony serve`. Once I tried to access `localhost:8000`, I had this warning in the terminal : `[Web Server/PHP ] Jun 22 13:47:55 |WARN | SERVER GET  (404) / ip="::1"`.

Moreover, the page I had was symfony's default page saying "#Page not found".

I checked the existing routes and I had `default                    ANY      ANY      ANY    /`.

I also checked the `DefaultController`, but everything looks fine, since it is the auto generated controller...

I don't know what else to check, how could I get this default page working ?

Comment: When I make a DefaultController using "bin/console make:controller Default" then the default url becomes /default and I have to go into the controller to change it.  And the route name is actually index and not default.  Did you adjust your controller?  I suppose you could also try the magical clearing of the cache though you should not have to.

Comment: Clearing cache is indeed magical, it worked after clearing it ! Thank you !

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar issue : I had run `symfony server:start` and was even seeing it react to my entering HTTP addresses in the browser, but I kept having that "# Page not found" message.

Quite simply, my symfony project was in `Group/SubGroup/Project`... and I was running `symfony server:start` from `Group/SubGroup`. When I stopped Symfony and ran it again from `Group/SubGroup/Project`, it worked like a charm.

A beginner's mistake, to be sure, but beginners use this site too.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the symfony project? It will show if you didn't run the symfony project. Run the project from terminal.

```
cd my-project/
symfony server:start
```

Answer (score 0):

ip="::1" is the localhost on windows and wsl 2. Symfony server listen on 127.0.0.1:8000.
You must edit the windows hosts file at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.
Add this line : 127.0.0.1:8000  localhost:8000
It works for me.

Comment: The question was about a routing issue, not about a mapping issue (the poster was able to connect to her/his Symfony instance, but wasn't served the expected page), so you might either want to consider taking your answer back, or to answer the question at hand in a meaningful way.